# Overlapping Gaussian output distributions for HMM states

Tags: normal-distribution, hidden-markov-model

The emission probabilities of a 2-state HMM model have overlapping Gaussian distributions with equal mean values. If the observed data sequence X is given, is it possible to infer the state sequence of the Markov process which generated the observed data?

[image: Here S = j represents the state]

Comment: It is possible to make inference on that sequence of states, not to "find it".

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry for the wrong use of terms. Could you explain a bit more?  I am confused with this:  For a GMM, this could be difficult as I understand: if there is such an overlap, estimating the corresponding state is difficult. But how is it possible for an HMM?

Comment: Given all parameters in the model, and the observations, one can derive the probability of a given sequence of states.

Comment: Also, I read that if there was no overlap between the two distributions, the markov states are not hidden- since there is a unique and unambiguous mapping for the observations to the states. (Li Deng and D. O’Shaughnessy: Speech Processing- A dynamic and optimization oriented approach, June 2003 )

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you very much. I think I need to dive into HMM to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

A Gaussian is not only represented by its mean but also by its variance. The variances will be very different for each Gaussian in this case and they are taking into account in the HMM. Basically, if each of these Gaussian is associated with one hidden state of the HMM, the likelihood of a data sample with respect to each of the state will be different.

Even out of an HMM context, you can intuitively see that a sample $X=5$ has "more chances" of having been generated by the red Gaussian than by the blue one. More formally its likelihood with respect to the red Gaussian is greater that its likelihood with respect to the blue Gaussian.

$P(X=5|\mu_{red}, \sigma_{red}) > P(X=5|\mu_{blue}, \sigma_{blue})$

Opposite to this a sample $X=0$ will have a higher likelihood with respect to the blue Gaussian.

These likelihood are taken into account when training an HMM as well as when using the Viterbi algorithm, that allows for the estimation of the most probable sequence of hidden states given an observation sequence.